# Can I give my own application?

Tags: android, payment, google-play

Yesterday I published my first paid app.
I can not buy it myself right?
Is it possible to give access to the paid version to other users?
For example, give the paid version for a particular user.

thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two solutions:

1. build an apk and send it to them.
2. Let them buy it and refund them.

Comment: Keep in mind that they will not get updates if you refund the play store purchase, and if you use licensing services in your app, it will return not licensed after a refund.

Answer (score 1):

You could build the apk and email it to them. However, they wouldn't get updates through the Play store.

Comment: What has self-signing got to do with it? Do you mean sign it differently than the signing key used on the store version?

Comment: the signing is unimportant. Could use the debug key, too.

Comment: I've not done this for over a year, I remember signing the apk but obviously that wasn't necessary...

Comment: Unsigned apks can't be installed, but there is no need to sign it with the real key, the debug key would be good enough, too (just make sure you use the same otherwise you can't send an updated version without forcing to uninstall first...)